# Power Arduino Due and 6 servo motor with Battery

Tags: power, motor, arduino-due, servo, battery

I would like to create a project contains 6 servo motors and Arduino Due board, but I have no idea how to operate should I use only a 9V battery only or in addition to 4 AAA battery?

Comment: That highly depends on the servo motors and how long this project should last with the batteries. You need to give us more details. Look at the data sheets for the servos and see, how much current they draw. With this and the capacity of your batteries you can estimate if this can work. For this also refer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140960/how-much-current-can-you-pull-safely-off-a-standard-aaa-battery)

Comment: Hello, 
 i want to know what is the best way to power an arduino due and a 6 servo motors and a HC-05 bluetooth module.

Since the arduino due operating voltage is 3.3V an the servo motors operating voltage is 4.8 ~7.2V  and the HC-05 bluetooth module can operate with 3.3v.

What is the best way to power them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best way in general. With your setup you may use a 9V battery as input for the Due (over the power jack, which wants voltage between 7V and 12V) and using a voltage regulator to get maybe 6V from your 9V battery voltage for your servos. Make sure, you get a regulator that can give you enough current for the 6 servos (You can find this info in the datasheet of the servo motors).

Of course you can also drive your project with 2 different battery packages, like you have described it in your question. Note, that you have to connect both grounds to make this work.